Is there a way to fix can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes when copying files between s3 buckets
I am trying to write a python script that will move specific files from source s3 bucket to target s3 bucket. The objective is to copy specific files to the target bucket in the initial run. on the second run, it compares the max lastmodified date in target with the lastmodified date in the source, then it uses that to copy new files in the source to the target.
This is what I have written
import boto3
import os
from datetime import datetime, timezone


def get_max_last_modified_time(bucket):
    """
    Get the maximum Last Modified time of files in an S3 bucket.
    
    Args:
    - bucket (str): The name of the S3 bucket.
    
    Returns:
    - datetime: The maximum Last Modified time of files in the bucket (timezone-aware).
    """
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket)
    files = response.get('Contents', [])
    if not files:
        return None
    # Convert Last Modified timestamps to datetime objects with UTC timezone
    last_modified_times = [file['LastModified'].astimezone(timezone.utc) for file in files]
    # Return the maximum Last Modified time as a timezone-aware datetime object
    return max(last_modified_times)




def copy_files(source_bucket, target_bucket):
    """
    Copy new files from source bucket to target bucket, excluding files containing 'example' in their filename.
    
    Args:
    - source_bucket (str): The name of the source bucket.
    - target_bucket (str): The name of the target bucket.
    
    Returns:
    - None
    """
    # Initialize the S3 client
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    # Get the maximum Last Modified time of files in the source bucket
    source_max_last_modified_time = get_max_last_modified_time(source_bucket)
    
    # Get the maximum Last Modified time of files in the target bucket
    target_max_last_modified_time = get_max_last_modified_time(target_bucket)
    
    # If there are no files in the target bucket, set the maximum Last Modified time to None
    if not target_max_last_modified_time:
        target_max_last_modified_time = datetime.min
    
    # List objects in the source bucket
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=source_bucket)
    files = response.get('Contents', [])
    
    # Iterate over the files in the source bucket
    for file_obj in files:
        file_key = file_obj['Key']
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_key)
        
        # Check if the file name contains 'example'
        if 'example' in file_name.lower():
            print(f"File containing 'example' found: '{file_name}'")
        else:
            # Get the Last Modified time of the file in the source bucket
            source_last_modified_time = file_obj['LastModified']
            
            # Skip files that have not been modified since the last execution
            if source_last_modified_time > target_max_last_modified_time:
                # Copy the file to the target bucket
                s3_client.copy_object(
                    Bucket=target_bucket,
                    CopySource={'Bucket': source_bucket, 'Key': file_key},
                    Key=file_key
                )
                print(f"Successfully copied new file '{file_name}' from '{source_bucket}' to '{target_bucket}'")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Specify the source and target bucket names
    source_bucket = 'queen-data-lake'
    target_bucket = 'queen-output'
    
    # Call the copy_files function
    copy_files(source_bucket, target_bucket)

I seem to be getting this error. also I wonder if this is an effective approach to handle millions of file
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/06/2zj_616d5vx22y29nq1jq2hc0000gn/T/ipykernel_30361/3639448357.py in <module>
    120 
    121     # Call the copy_files function
--> 122     copy_files(source_bucket, target_bucket)

/var/folders/06/2zj_616d5vx22y29nq1jq2hc0000gn/T/ipykernel_30361/3639448357.py in copy_files(source_bucket, target_bucket)

    105 
    106             # Skip files that have not been modified since the last execution
--> 107             if source_last_modified_time > target_max_last_modified_time:
    108                 # Copy the file to the target bucket
    109                 s3_client.copy_object(

TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes


Side-note: The AWS CLI aws s3 sync command can do this. Just mentioning it in case you didn't know.

Your issue seems to be that the program is attempting to compare a timestamp against a timestamp that has a timezone. It is being caused by your usage of .astimezone(timezone.utc). If you remove that, it should work fine (but I didn't test it).
By the way, list_objects_v2() only returns a maximum of 1000 objects per call. Therefore, if your bucket has more than 1000 objects, your code will misbehave.
You mention that you might want to handle "millions of files". Retrieving the listing from both buckets will be time-consuming.
Better ways to replicate the files would be:

S3 replication can automatically replicate new objects between buckets
Creating an S3 Event that triggers an AWS Lambda function whenever a new object is created, and the Lambda function copies the file immediately (without the need to run code as a batch)


Thanks alot for your response and the suggestion using Lambda function makes sense but the usecase requires us to do it that was. If the list_objects_v2() returns 1000 objects, is there a way around that

You can loop the calls to list_objects_v2() using next_token to get the next batch of 1000. Or, instead of using the client method you can use the resource method to get objects and it does the pagination for you. See: Lookup Key from S3 Bucket using Boto Just be aware that if there are lots of objects, your code will be slow!
